# Securely using a variable in URL in a Flask webapp

Tags: security, url, flask

I am using Flask to make a webappthat will contain a variable within the URL (example below).

```
@app.route('/landingpage/<id>')  # /landingpage/A
def landing_page(id):
    # Storage of a hashed <id>...
```

My question relates to the variable within the URL which could contain confidential information, which should not be accessible to anyone other than the person entering the URL.

Would it be sufficient for the connection to be made over HTTPS to prevent anyone else accessing the variable prior to it being stored in a hashed format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID in url, flask have support for this type of url, and i recommend to use this lib [flask-uuid](https://github.com/wbolster/flask-uuid) to gerate the uuid to your client access

```
from flask_uuid import FlaskUUID

flask_uuid = FlaskUUID()
flask_uuid.init_app(app)

@app.route('/personalID')  
def gerate_uuid():
    return make_response({'uuid':uuid.uuid4()})

@app.route('/landingpage/<uuid:id>')  # /landingpage/A
def landing_page(id):
    return id  # 'id' is a uuid.UUID instance
```

Comment: FlaskUUID seems very promising, thank you. 

One thing I can't immediately see is if it is possible to 'decode' the UUID to retreive the original variable (<id> in the above example)?

Comment: yes, you can, but using the jwt lib, look my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186473/is-there-a-way-to-login-a-user-using-flask-socket-io/60189202#60189202, normally jwt is used for Auth, but you can do it too

Comment: In which case, I believe it might be easier to simply hash the variable and store that directly rather than using a combination of FlaskUUID and jwt. Assuming I can take care of hashing the ID, my original question remains regarding HTTPS and whether the variable can be considered secure.

Comment: Yep, it remains safe, because the SSL will work in Application Layer, and the URL make part of application layer, so yep, you can transmit your UUID or token in URL with no problems